# Submit button doesn't hit controller due to [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()] And Disabled Cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am using  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() , but due to this code , when i click on submit, it doesn't hit action in controller.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "COntroller",null, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "$('#dvLoading').removeClass('displayNone');", OnSuccess = "ShowResultUpsID(data);", OnFailure = "$('#dvLoading').addClass('displayNone'); Showerror(); scrollToTop();" }, new { @id = "CreateID", @Name = "CreateID" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

}
```

below is my Action

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
 public ActionResult MyAction(Model object)
 {
 }
```

**Note**: with cookie disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` library to your project.
which help you to work with Html Ajax forms.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(resolve) { console.log(resolve) }
    function OnFailure(error) { console.log(error) }
    function OnComplete(resolve) { console.log(resolve) }
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddUser", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnComplete = "OnComplete", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
    <button>Save</button>

}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddUser(UserModel model)
{
   return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is cookies is disable .Can some one please guide me how to work with Anty forgery Token when Cookies is disable .?